# Convert Excel column date with different patterns - Oracle PLSQL

Tags: sql, excel, oracle, sqldatetime

I'm trying to convert the column **DATA_EMISSAO** which has a **char** format but contains all dates for the Table (it only contains dates).

The problem is: the way information was loaded into Oracle let the row set with different patterns as shown below:

[image]

As you can see there are 2 patterns: 'DD/MM/YYYY' and Excel's Date number format.

1) First I tried to convert them with the code:

```
  select distinct to_char(DATA_EMISSAO, 'DD-MM-YYYY') from MASTERSAF;
```

But got the error:

```
  ORA-01722: invalid number
  01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
  *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
  *Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

2) Then I tried the following:

```
  select distinct to_char(to_date(DATA_EMISSAO, 'DD-MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY') from MASTERSAF;
```

But got no success...

```
   ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
   01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
   *Cause:    
   *Action:
```

Do you think it should be better to construct a condition to read each row condition and apply the proper "transformation"?

Also, I don't know why, but if I run

```
   select to_char(to_date(DATA_EMISSAO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 0, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as DATES2 from MASTERSAF;
```

It seems to go fine, but if I put a **distinct** before,

```
                select distinct to_char(to_date(DATA_EMISSAO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') + 0, 'DD/MM/YYYY') as DATES2 from MASTERSAF;
```

I get the following error:

```
    ORA-01847: day of month must be between 1 and last day of month
    01847. 00000 -  "day of month must be between 1 and last day of month"
    *Cause:    
    *Action:
```

Do you have an idea to correct the dates?
(unfortunately I cannot change on excel because the database is too large....)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` statement to match the different formats and convert them each to a date using the appropriate method (`DD/MM/YYYY` can be converted using `TO_DATE` and a single number can be converted by adding days to `1900-01-01`):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dates ( date_emissao ) AS
SELECT '12/08/2016' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '42716' FROM DUAL
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( date_emissao, '^\d+$' )
       THEN DATE '1900-01-01' + TO_NUMBER( date_emissao )
       ELSE TO_DATE( date_emissao, 'DD/MM/YYYY' )
       END AS date_emissao
FROM   dates;
```

**Output**:

```
| DATE_EMISSAO |
| :----------- |
| 2016-08-12   |
| 2016-12-14   |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f398e139ee30e413395b31a5e2052d18)*

Comment: thank you very much! By the way, why I cannot put a "select distinct" on the result? I tried `select distinct DATE_EMISSAO from [**the code you indicated**]` but got the error `ORA-01843: not a valid month`.

Comment: @Petter_Mendes [db<>fiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=78557d9d205eaff7f7a44244df295dfb) Just add the `DISTINCT` keyword straight after the `SELECT` and before the first column.

Comment: Yes, I did the following: 
`SELECT  DISTINCT  DATE_EMISSAO FROM (SELECT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(DATE_EMISSAO, '^\d+$') THEN DATE '19000-01-01' TO_NUMBER(DATE_EMISSAO) ELSE TO_DATE(DATE_EMISSAO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') END AS DATA_EMISSAO FROM MASTERSAF)`;

And After running it I got the following error: `ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 3`.

Comment: If I put directly in the code `SELECT  DISTINCT  CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(DATE_EMISSAO, '^\d+$') THEN DATE '19000-01-01' TO_NUMBER(DATE_EMISSAO) ELSE TO_DATE(DATE_EMISSAO, 'DD/MM/YYYY') END AS DATA_EMISSAO FROM MASTERSAF` 
I get the error: `ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:`

Comment: @Petter_Mendes `1900` only has 2 zeroes and you are missing the `+` symbol after the date literal.

Comment: yes, sorry for the typos in the post but the code I ran was correct. Sorry for my dummy question. So, the code should be **I)** `SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( DATA_EMISSAO, '^\d+$' ) THEN DATE '1900-01-01' + TO_NUMBER( DATA_EMISSAO ) ELSE TO_DATE( DATA_EMISSAO, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) END AS DATA_EMISSAO FROM MASTERSAF;`

Comment: or 
**II)** `SELECT DISTINCT DATA_EMISSAO (SELECT DISTINCT CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( DATA_EMISSAO, '^\d+$' ) THEN DATE '1900-01-01' + TO_NUMBER( DATA_EMISSAO ) ELSE TO_DATE( DATA_EMISSAO, 'DD/MM/YYYY' ) END AS DATA_EMISSAO FROM MASTERSAF);`        
 but as I mentioned the error persisted either way.